# Pandas assign column values using array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to assign values to specific columns, but in this case column names and values are present in array.

Below is my code.

But Col-1 is not getting assigned with 1,23,3

Please help me identifying the issue in the below code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col-1', 'Col-2']);
key = ['Col-1']
v= [1,23,3]

df[key] = [v]
```

Comment: it should be `df[key[0]] = v`

Comment: Your first solution is not dynamic. What if i want something below `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col-1', 'Col-2', 'Col-3']);
key = ['Col-1','Col-2']
v= [[1,23,3],[2,3,4]]
df[key] = [v]`

Comment: In the current case both column names and values are present in arrays. If its hardcoding means whatever link shared would help

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col-1', 'Col-2', 'Col-3'])
key = ['Col-1', 'Col-2']
v = [[1, 23, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
for i,j in zip(key,v):
    df[i] = j

print(df)
```

output

```
   Col-1  Col-2 Col-3
0      1      2   NaN
1     23      3   NaN
2      3      4   NaN
```

Comment: This is the expected result. But was wondering is there any other alternative to looping

Answer (score 0):

There is one more method

use transposed list and make it dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col-1', 'Col-2', 'Col-3'])
key = ['Col-1', 'Col-2']
v = [[1, 23, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
df[key] = pd.DataFrame(list(map(list, zip(*v))))

print(df)
```